# "Bad API request, invalid or expired api_user_key"

Tags: javascript, php, api, pastebin

So my website makes a AJAX request to a PHP page on my website. It first logs in and gets the users Pastebin session ID and then uses that to view all pastes made by that user. Only problem is I keep getting an error: Bad API request, invalid or expired api_user_key. I think I did the session ID part correct (I even tried generating one with http://pastebin.com/api/api_login.php

Javascript code:

```
var logindata = {};
var sessionid;

$("#login").click(function() {
    $.each($('#loginform').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        logindata[field.name] = field.value;
    });

    $.get("pb_login.php?username=" + logindata['pastebinusername'] + "&password=" + logindata['pastebinpassword'], function(data, status) {
        alert(data);
        sessionid = data;

        $.get("pb_getlists.php?sessionid=" + sessionid, function(data, status) {
            alert(sessionid);
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

pb_login.php

```
<?php
$api_dev_key = 'API key here';
$api_user_name = urlencode($_GET['username']);
$api_user_password = urlencode($_GET['password']);
$url = 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_login.php';

$ch = curl_init($url); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'api_dev_key='.$api_dev_key.'&api_user_name='.$api_user_name.'&api_user_password='.$api_user_password.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
?>
```

pb_getlists.php

```
<?php
$api_dev_key = 'API key here';
$api_user_key = $_GET['sessionid'];
//$api_user_key = '43ded5a66e8ed08603804fe2487c8ab7';
$api_results_limit = '250';
$url = 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'api_option=list&api_user_key='.$api_user_key.'&api_dev_key='.$api_dev_key.'&api_results_limit='.$api_results_limit.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
?>
```

Thanks in advance. :)

EDIT: I'm really starting to think it's a problem with Pastebin's API. I wouldn't be surprised if it was something stupid I messed up, but I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 1):

Yay. I'm an idiot.

I whitelisted the wrong IP (you need to whitelist an IP to use the Pastebin API). I was testing with a LAMP VM and forgot to change it when I started doing stuff on my actual website.